# Run Gradle build offline in a docker container

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to run `gradle build test` on my Kotlin app in a docker container which does not have access to the internet hence I copy Gradle in Dockerfile 
`ADD https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip /usr/bin/gradle.zip`
but the problem is that my app has got the following plugin in the app.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.40"
}
```

so how would I go about to add these plugins to my container before running gradle `offline` in container?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your `GRADLE_USER_HOME` into the container as well. It contains Gradle wrapper distributions, plugins and dependencies. By default, `GRADLE_USER_HOME` is `~/.gradle` directory.

I suppose, what you can do is run your full build once in a fresh container with Internets access and then just copy `/root/.gradle` (or whatever your user is configured to be inside the container) from it. Or just use that existing container as a base for your build image.